# using the function sum() with a list comprehension in python

Tags: python, list, function, sum, list-comprehension

I have a question that requires a list comprehension and **MUST** use  the **sum()** function, it may not be the best way but that is what is asked. Please read the question below:

**Question:**
Write a function word_count(string, word) that uses a list comprehension and the sum() function to count the number the number of times a word appears in a string. Apply this to the dickens string. Hint: the sum() function can be used to add the elements of a list. For instance,
sum([1, 2, 3]) 
would return 6. Is there a problem with certain words? Which ones and why? Try using the strip string method (we'll revisit this later when we talk about regular expressions).

String used:

```
dickens = """
It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, 
it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness, it was the epoch of belief, 
it was the epoch of incredulity, it was the season of Light, it was the season of Darkness, 
it was the spring of hope, it was the winter of despair, we had everything before us, we had 
nothing before us, we were all going direct to Heaven, we were all going direct the other way -
in short, the period was so far like the present period, that some of its noisiest authorities 
insisted on its being received, for good or for evil, in the superlative degree of comparison only.
"""

def word_count(s, w):
   return [word for word in s.strip().split() if w == word ]
print(word_count(dickens, "it"))

output= ['it', 'it', 'it', 'it', 'it', 'it', 'it', 'it', 'it']
```

So basically from here, using the sum function, how can I get the answer to sum all elements to be 9.

```
def word_count(s, w):
   return sum([word for word in s.strip().split() if w == word ])

print(word_count(dickens, "it"))
```

This does not work for me but must look something like this.

Thanks

Comment: `len(your_array)`?

Comment: `len(word_count(dickens, "it"))`

Comment: He can't use len, read the question

Comment: @AdrianoMartins sorry we are here to solve problems not answer homework questions. Furthermore, your initial answer was `sum(['it', 'it', ..., 'it'])`, I don't think you have much of a claim for being condescending.

Comment: @JahKnows I'm not trying to be condescending, I'm just asking people who downvoted me to read the question before they do it. Most of them just downvoted for not using the `len(array)`, if they read the question they would know why I did not use it. Also, feel free to look at the edits, I have not coded this sum nor ever used it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have to use `sum()` for counting purposes, try treating every occurrence of the word as 1. Although this is a suboptimal solution, it's probably right under the given requirements.

```
sum([1 for word in s.strip().split() if w == word ])
     ^
```

It is equivalent to:

```
sum([1, 1, 1, 1, ......])
```

There are also other forms of (essentially the same) solution:

```
sum(w == word for word in s.strip().split())
```

It is interpreted as

```
sum( (w == word) for word in s.strip().split() )
```

and boolean values are treated as ones and zeros when added, so you get the number of matching words.

The latter approach is faster than the first because it creates a generator object instead of a real list full of 1's.

Comment: `sum(w == word for word in s.split())` is a simpler way to do the job.

Comment: If you really need to micro-optimize, I'd bet (although I wouldn't bet much without testing) that `sum(map(w.__eq__, s.strip(),split()))` is faster than the genexpr version.  (The main reason it might not be faster is that bound methods get in the way a bit for builtin types.)

Comment: On my machine, the `map()` solution is only a tiny bit faster: 36.8 seconds rather than 37.8 according to `timeit()`

Comment: @kindall Well, at least I guessed right that it is faster. Too bad I didn't bet much. :) The difference might be amplified with much larger lists, but considering that each list is the words in a line of text, that almost certainly isn't relevant, even if micro-optimizing mattered in the first place (it probably doesn't), so I'd definitely stick with your easier-to-explain version. But since you were talking about "faster", I figured it was worth mentioning (and testing).

Answer (score 4):

Just add 1 to the array if it exists:

```
def word_count(s, w):
   return sum(1 for word in s.strip().split() if w == word)
```

*It is explicit on the question that he can't use `len`, he must use sum.*

Comment: That's the one of the most un-optimal solution to this problem.

Comment: Maybe if you read the question, you will see that he can't use len

Comment: Yeah sorry, mate!

Comment: You don't need the braces `[]` inside `sum` and it will be a bit more efficient as the list will not be created.

Comment: @UbdusSamad Actually, `sum(1 for …)` is often more optimal than `len([x for …])`, because it doesn't have to build a list that's not being used for any purpose but getting its length. For small inputs like this it won't matter either way, but if they're big enough to matter—try counting, say, the number of values <0.95 in a list of 100M random numbers in `[0,1)`, and `sum` takes less time (and a lot less space). There's a reason this is a recipe in the `itertools` docs.

Comment: It may or may not be faster to do `sum(w==word for word in s.strip().split())`, or `sum(map(w.__eq__, s.strip().split())`. But that's probably not as clear—it relies on readers implicitly understanding that `True` and `False` convert to 1 and 0, and, in the second case, understanding bound methods.

Comment: @AdrianoMartins That's exactly what i needed, thanks!

Comment: @abarnert , I'll try testing it and see what happens, thanks for sharing the info. :)

Answer (score 2):

Others like Adriano here gave good answers.

If what you wanted to accomplish was to count the occurrences of 'it', you can use `count(substr)` function for strings.

In your case,

```
print(dickens.lower().count('it')) # prints 13
```

---

EDIT: added `lower()`, thanks coldspeed!

Comment: I think you meant `dickens.lower().count('it')` Although keep in mind this will count "it" even if it is part of a larger word.

Comment: Made changes. Thanks!

Answer (score -4):

Use the length of the list comprehension.

```
def word_count(s, w):
    return sum([1 for word in s.strip().split() if w == word ])
print(word_count(dickens, "it"))
```